# quickest way of filtering a list in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

Give the data below for a payload/list of pay items,

```
{
   "details":{
      "totalPay":482.66,
      "currency":"OMR",
      "contributions":48.24,
      "sections":[
         {
            "name":"Earnings",
            "value":519.41,
            "details":[
               {
                  "name":"Overtime",
                  "value":60,
                  "notes":"Border OT",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"H R A",
                  "value":96,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"LIVING ALLOWANCE",
                  "value":32,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"T A",
                  "value":32,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Basic salary",
                  "value":299.408,
                  "notes":"",
                  "currency":"OMR"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Deductions",
            "value":36.75,
            "details":[
               {
                  "name":"PASI - Employee (7%) - Employee",
                  "value":32.1586,
                  "notes":null,
                  "currency":"OMR"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Social Security Recovery (1%) - Employee",
                  "value":4.5941,
                  "notes":null,
                  "currency":"OMR"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I would like get values for specific names. For e.g I would like to get the value for Basic salary which is 299.488

My script stops working when i use the below,

```
{% set basicSalary = (data.details.sections.details | selectattr('name', 'eq', 'Basic salary')| (attribute='value')%}
```

What would be the shortest and quickest way of doing this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: all i see is "unknown error" on the console. not very helpful, i agree

Comment: I'm confused; in the event of a templating error, jinja2 raises a `TemplateSyntaxError` with details about the problem. Can you update your question to include an [mcve] that reproduces the behavior you're asking about?

Comment: ...but I note that `data.details.sections.details` isn't a valid expression; `data.details.sections` is a list; it doesn't have a `details` member. You could write something like `data.details.sections[0].details`, or you could feed `data.details.sections` to `selectattr`, but what you're doing right now is only going to result in an error.